# Raster calculator con statement not working in ModelBuilder in ArcGIS 10.3

Tags: arcgis-desktop, modelbuilder, arcgis-10.3, error-000539

I am trying to use raster calculator using a con statement loop for 3 rasters. All rasters are 10*10. My command is

```
Con(("hydro_sg2.tif" == 1), 1, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 2) & ("avg_slope1.tif" < 4)), 1, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 2) & ("avg_slope1.tif" >= 4) & ("avg_slope1.tif" <= 6) & ("kfactor_2.tif" < 0.32)), 2, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 2) & ("avg_slope1.tif" >= 4) & ("avg_slope1.tif" <= 6) & ("kfactor_2.tif" >= 0.32)), 3, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 2) & ("avg_slope1.tif" > 6)), 4, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 3) & ("avg_slope1.tif" < 2)), 1, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 3) & ("avg_slope1.tif" >= 2) & ("avg_slope1.tif" <= 6) & ("kfactor_2.tif" < 0.28)), 2, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 3) & ("avg_slope1.tif" >= 2) & ("avg_slope1.tif" <= 6) & ("kfactor_2.tif" >= 0.28)), 3, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 3) & ("avg_slope1.tif" > 6)), 4, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 4) & ("avg_slope1.tif" < 2) & ("kfactor_2.tif" < 0.28)), 1, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 4) & ("avg_slope1.tif" < 2) & ("kfactor_2.tif" >= 0.28)), 2, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 4) & ("avg_slope1.tif" >= 2) & ("avg_slope1.tif" <= 4)), 3, 
Con((("hydro_sg2.tif" == 4) & ("avg_slope1.tif" > 4)), 4)))))))))))))
```

If I run the command just in raster calculator , it works fine ... if I use it in model builder I ma getting an error

```
ERROR 000539: Error running expression: rcexec() 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<expression>", line 1, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 17, in rcexec
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 255, in Con
    where_clause)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Utils.py", line 53, in swapper
    result = wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
  File "c:\program files (x86)\arcgis\desktop10.3\arcpy\arcpy\sa\Functions.py", line 239, in Wrapper
    ["IfThen", in_conditional_raster, in_true_raster_or_constant])
RuntimeError: ERROR 999998: Unexpected Error
```

.

Any suggestions ???

Comment: I couldn't find any syntax problem with it, did you try using the native ESRI raster format? it sometimes makes the difference, you can batch convert rasters of other formats to GRID using the Raster to Raster tool.

Comment: Can you please post a screenshot of your model?

Comment: Finally, I added a % sign before and after each tif file in each line and it worked. For eg. "%hydro_sg2.tif%"

Comment: Would you mind putting that as an answer and accepting it? so that other people who are looking for a similar solution can see the question has an accepted solution? thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally, I added a % sign before and after each tif file in each line and it worked. For eg. "%hydro_sg2.tif%"